# Jetty 9 for security reasons do not want to display Stacktraces

Tags: spring, jetty-9

Versions: jetty-9.4.38.v20210224, logging Slf4jLog, Spring Boot v2.4.4, Spring v5.3.5.

A pentest was performed in our code and after sending malformed headers with cUrl we can obtain the following response, revealing Stacktrace and exposing that its using Jetty:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 400 Bad header value for X-Forwarded-Port</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 400 Bad header value for X-Forwarded-Port</h2>
<table>
<tr><th>URI:</th><td>/</td></tr>
<tr><th>STATUS:</th><td>400</td></tr>
<tr><th>MESSAGE:</th><td>Bad header value for X-Forwarded-Port</td></tr>
<tr><th>SERVLET:</th><td>-</td></tr>
<tr><th>CAUSED BY:</th><td>org.eclipse.jetty.http.BadMessageException: 400: Bad header value for X-Forwarded-Port</td></tr>
<tr><th>CAUSED BY:</th><td>java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: &quot;zwrtxqvas9lm4kzkw0&quot;</td></tr>
</table>
<h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>org.eclipse.jetty.http.BadMessageException: 400: Bad header value for X-Forwarded-Port
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ForwardedRequestCustomizer.onError(ForwardedRequestCustomizer.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ForwardedRequestCustomizer.customize(ForwardedRequestCustomizer.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:882)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1036)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: &quot;zwrtxqvas9lm4kzkw0&quot;
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.HostPort.parsePort(HostPort.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ForwardedRequestCustomizer$Forwarded.handleForwardedPort(ForwardedRequestCustomizer.java:856)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ForwardedRequestCustomizer.customize(ForwardedRequestCustomizer.java:473)
    ... 15 more
</pre>

</body>
</html>
```

Previously to not expose Jetty version i disabled the SendServerVersion but could not figure out any configuration to disable the Stacktraces.

```
@Configuration
public class JettyConfiguration implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<JettyServletWebServerFactory> {

    @Override
    public void customize(JettyServletWebServerFactory factory) {

        factory.addServerCustomizers(server -> {

            /* StatisticsHandler needed for graceful shutdown */
            StatisticsHandler statisticsHandler = new StatisticsHandler();
            statisticsHandler.setHandler(server.getHandler());
            server.setHandler(statisticsHandler);

            /* Autoforwarded Configuration */
            for (Connector connector : server.getConnectors()) {
                ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = connector.getDefaultConnectionFactory();
                if (connectionFactory instanceof HttpConnectionFactory) {
                    HttpConnectionFactory defaultConnectionFactory = (HttpConnectionFactory) connectionFactory;
                    HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration = defaultConnectionFactory.getHttpConfiguration();
                    httpConfiguration.setSendServerVersion(false);
                    httpConfiguration.addCustomizer(new ForwardedRequestCustomizer());
                }
            }

        });

    }

}
```

What is the best approach to disable the Stacktraces? TIA

Answer (score 1):

Jetty as most web servers will provide a default exception handler. If you don't like that default exception handler then register yours.

Just provide an ExceptionHandler for RunntimeException and provide a general error. For example backend failed please try again later with status 500.

There are many articles on how to implement an exception handler in spring. I add one just for reference

[exception handling spring boot](https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-exception-handling/)

Comment: I tried to use the ControllerAdvice but the exception was thrown at ErrorHandler level, i ended up overriding its handle method.

Answer (score 0):

First started by trying to fix the issue by implementing a GlobalExceptionHandler using @ControllerAdvice, unfortunately this did not seemed to be triggered, i believe it is related with the fact that its meant for exceptions thrown by MVC.

The request crafted by the pen-tester was using malformed headers, so the error was thrown by ErrorHandler, i ended up creating my own ErrorHandler and overriding the handle method.

This seems to do the trick but probably too strict, i am afraid this will make difficult debugging in the future. Any recommendations or improvements? Thanks

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.*;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ErrorHandler;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyServerCustomizer;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@Configuration
public class JettyConfiguration implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<JettyServletWebServerFactory> {

    @Override
    public void customize(JettyServletWebServerFactory factory) {

        JettyServerCustomizer customizer = server -> {
            MyErrorHandler myErrorHandler = new MyErrorHandler();
            myErrorHandler.setShowStacks(false);
            myErrorHandler.setShowMessageInTitle(false);
            myErrorHandler.setShowServlet(false);
            server.setErrorHandler(myErrorHandler);
        };
        factory.addServerCustomizers(customizer);

        factory.addServerCustomizers(server -> {

            /* Autoforwarded Configuration */
            for (Connector connector : server.getConnectors()) {
                ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = connector.getDefaultConnectionFactory();
                if (connectionFactory instanceof HttpConnectionFactory) {
                    HttpConnectionFactory defaultConnectionFactory = (HttpConnectionFactory) connectionFactory;
                    HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration = defaultConnectionFactory.getHttpConfiguration();
                    httpConfiguration.setSendServerVersion(false);
                    httpConfiguration.addCustomizer(new ForwardedRequestCustomizer());
                }
            }

        });

    }


    static class MyErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler {

        @Override
        public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException
        {
            //doError(target, baseRequest, request, response);
        }

    }

}
```